# wp_mail not working on a wordpress custom plugin file

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am having a wierd issue. I am using "WP Email Template" plugin with mandrill. I am also using a custom file inside "theme-my-login" plugin which needs to send an email after a $_POST is recieved. Here is a code

```
$location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

global $wpdb;

if ( ! isset( $wpdb ) ) { 
    include( $location . '/wp-config.php' );
}

global $current_user;

/************** Wp_mail Works Fine when placed here *************/
if( isset( $_POST['organisation_name'] ) ) {    
/************** Wp_mail doesnot Work when placed here *************/
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
}
```

Wp mail works just fine when placed outside isset($_POST) but when placed inside it doesnot work. I have doubled checked and the if statement is properly executed.
EDIT: Here is Print_r($_POST) before the condition
Well nothing interesting

```
Array
(
    [organisation_name] => iDevels
    [representative_name] => Test Ato
    [representative_contact] => 
    [course-name] => ITIL 2011
    [course-level] => Foundation (3 days)
    [start-date] => 17/02/2015
    [end-date] => 19/02/2015
    [no-candidate] => 2
    [trainer-required] => true
    [trainer-name] => 
    [exam-required] => true
    [exam-date] => 19/02/2015
    [exam-time] => 12:00
    [exam-type] => Paper
    [proctor-name] => 
    [delivery-contact] => asdasd
    [delivery-phone] => 234234
    [delivery-address] => asdasd
    [delivery-city] => asdasd
    [delivery-postcode] => asdasd
    [delivery-country] => AT
    [exam-papers] => delivery location
    [training-venue-location] => Same as delivery location
    [training-contact] => asdasd
    [training-phone] => 234234
    [training-address] => asdasd
    [training-city] => asdasd
    [training-postcode] => asdasd
    [training-country] => AT
    [_wpnonce] => cc65d65d0c
    [_wp_http_referer] => /customer-area/?settings=order-training
)
```

Comment: Can you please enter the following code above the `if` statement and paste here the result : `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";`

Comment: Thankyou @merianos for your time, its a long form but i have added the results in the edit

Comment: It's very strange ! The code you have provide us it should work. I don't really know what happens to your code :) Sorry that I can't give any further help :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it was sending mail before the condition. I just changed the mandrill settings from making API calls to actually using Mandrills SMTP settings and this solved the issue.